# after updating from room 2.2.6 to 2.3.0 I get an error: "You must annotate primary keys with @NonNull."

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

I updated room from `2.2.6` to `2.3.0` and started seeing weird errors in the compiled/generated java code at compile time. I do not see any errors in my `.kt` files or in the generated `.java` files in the directory `...build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/...` I only see the compile-time error that breaks the build.

**The full error I get:**

```
error: You must annotate primary keys with @NonNull. "version" is nullable. SQLite considers this a bug and Room does not allow it. See SQLite docs for details: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html
    private java.lang.Integer version;
```

When I look at the generated `.java` code I see that it is annotating it:

```
@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
@androidx.annotation.NonNull()
private java.lang.Integer version;
```

My Kotlin code is annotated as well:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
...
    @NonNull
    var version: Int? = null
```

My code worked fine and is well tested and proven to work using room `2.2.6`. I only started having this problem after updating to room `2.3.0`.

Old dependencies.gradle

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6"
```

Updated dependencies.gradle

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: because this : `var version: Int? = null` can be null, in java sphere it will be converted to a `Integer` object and not evaluated as a primitive `int`.  The error is quite explicit, primary keys should not be `null` - as a quick fix just make it `var int = -1`.  However consider creating the object with a matching constructor as a data class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't use `@NonNull` annotations - that's determined by your type itself, which in your case is a nullable `Int?`.

You'll need to change it to an `Int` and assign it a default value (i.e., `-1`).

Comment: Thanks, @ianhanniballake! Now that you point that out it makes a lot of sense. I wonder why it worked in the prior version of room? It has not had any problems the way it was before the update.