# Room 2.3.0 ignores @NonNull annotations

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

After updating Android Room from 2.2.6 to 2.3.0 it stopped processing `@androidx.annotation.NonNull` annotations, they are ignored now.

When installing the app after upgrade, I get:

```
Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

Example code that used to work in Room 2.2.6:

```
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "span_type")
var spanType: SpanType? = null
```

after upgrading to 2.3.0 generates changes in schema (I have both `exportSchema` and `room.schemaLocation` set):

[image]

In the example above `SpanType` is `enum`, but I also have these annotations on other fields, e.g. `@NonNull var objectId: Long? = null` and they also get ignored after upgrade.

I know I can use workarounds but this is not what I want to do - I searched through docs, release notes, etc. and couldn't find any info that `@NonNull` support is deprecated or removed. I also tested with previous kotlin version (1.4.x instead of 1.5.20) and there's no difference.

The closest SO question is probably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376196/after-updating-from-room-2-2-6-to-2-3-0-i-get-an-error-you-must-annotate-prima), but accepted answer is obviously wrong - kotlin supports `@NonNull` annotations.

Do you have any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: That answer you linked is correct. The nullability annotations are only intended for Java code because in Kotlin the nullability is indicated by whether or not you put a `?` after the type. It is contradictory that you are using `@NonNull` with a nullable property. It’s possible previous versions of Room accidentally checked for the annotation even in Kotlin code and that has been fixed now.

Comment: Additionally to what Tenfour04 says, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411928/how-to-annotate-column-as-not-null-using-android-room-persistence-library/44413561 for a list of supported Room annotations. It could be that even though the upgrade to 2.3 was technically a minor update, it might've had a breaking change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so according to the comments (thanks @Tenfour04 and @Ken Van Hoeylandt), there's no way to use `@NonNull` anymore.

**Why this was problem for me**

It seems that Room just disabled one of the security layers in enterprise apps - database constraints. It happened few times that my app crashed due to null check constraints and that was correct (concurrency issues where multiple threads operate on the same object). Now, when `@NonNull` doesn't work, instead of a crash, a database would get filled with junk data like `id=-1` because there's no way to set initial null value for fields holding primitive types, e.g. `@ColumnInfo(name = "object_id") lateinit var objectId: Long`.

**My workaround**

- For non-primitive types workaround is quite easy - I just replaced this:

```
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "span_type")
var spanType: SpanType? = null
```

with this:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "span_type")
lateinit var spanType: SpanType
```

Schema generated by Room doesn't change, all null checks like `if (spanType == null) {...}` can be replaced with `if (!::spanType.isInitialized) {...}`

- For primitive types workaround is little more complex

Given field:

```
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "object_id")
var objectId: Long? = null
```

cannot be converted to:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "object_id")
lateinit var objectId: Long
```

The first option is to replace Long with BigInteger:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "object_id")
lateinit var objectId: BigInteger
```

and write a `@TypeConverter` that converts BigInteger to Long. This works but BigInteger's in-memory size is significant ([see this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301249/how-much-space-does-biginteger-use)) and not ideal for Android.

Instead of using BigIntegers, I wrote simplier, lightweight wrapper for primitive types:

```
class LateinitPrimitive<T>(t: T?) where T : Number {
    var value: T? = t
}
```

so now I can declare:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "object_id")
lateinit var objectId: LateinitPrimitive<Long>
```

Adding necessary converters:

```
@TypeConverter
fun lateinitPrimitiveToLong(lateinitPrimitive: LateinitPrimitive<Long>): Long? = lateinitPrimitive.value

@TypeConverter
fun lateinitPrimitiveFromLong(value: Long?): LateinitPrimitive<Long>? = value?.let { LateinitPrimitive(value) }
```

I achieved the same functionality that I had prior to Room 2.3.0 - if `objectId` is missing I get plain old `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed`.